How to fix shiny terrain?
I have a code that loads terrain data from files. But it doesn't work how I want. This makes the terrain look shiny, which shouldn't happen.
public void LoadTerrainHeightMap(string[] heightInfo)
{
    TerrainData terrainData = Terrain.terrainData;
    int resolution = terrainData.heightmapResolution;

    float[,] heights = new float[resolution, resolution];

    for (int y = 0; y < resolution; y++)
    {
        if (y >= heightInfo.Length)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Insufficient data for terrain heightmap.");
            break;
        }

        string[] heightData = heightInfo[y].Split('-');
        for (int x = 0; x < resolution; x++)
        {
            if (x < heightData.Length && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(heightData[x]))
            {
                float height = float.Parse(heightData[x]);
                heights[x, y] = Mathf.Clamp01(height);
            }
        }
    }

    terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, heights);
}

public void LoadTerrainTextureMapLayers(string[] layers)
{
    TerrainData terrainData = Terrain.terrainData;

    terrainData.splatPrototypes = new SplatPrototype[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < layers.Length; i++)
    {
        terrainData.terrainLayers[i].diffuseTexture = Game.LoadTexture2D(layers[i]);
    }
}

void LoadAndApplyTerrainLayers(string[] textureInfoLines)
{
    TerrainData terrainData = Terrain.terrainData;
    int alphaMapWidth = terrainData.alphamapWidth;
    int alphaMapHeight = terrainData.alphamapHeight;

    float[,,] alphaMaps = new float[alphaMapWidth, alphaMapHeight, terrainData.alphamapLayers];

    for (int y = 0; y < textureInfoLines.Length; y++)
    {
        string[] layerData = textureInfoLines[y].Split('-');
        for (int x = 0; x < layerData.Length; x++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(layerData[x]))
            {
                int layer = int.Parse(layerData[x]);
                if (x >= 0 && x < alphaMapWidth && y >= 0 && y < alphaMapHeight)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < terrainData.alphamapLayers; i++)
                    {
                        alphaMaps[x, y, i] = i == layer ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Coordinates are out of range for the terrain's alpha map.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    terrainData.SetAlphamaps(0, 0, alphaMaps);
}

When this code is completed, the terrain begins to shine, I don’t understand where this can come from. I checked the terrain material, checked the layers that are loaded, but this did not give any result.
